# Proving that $x/(x+1)$ is continuous at $x=2$ by the definition

Tags: calculus, continuity

I came upon this question,

the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}$ is continuous at $x=2$ by the definition.

Do I have to show that limit at $x=2$ exits first? I am confused with the steps, can someone please help?

Comment: You need to show that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(2)|<\varepsilon$ if $|x-2|<\delta$. In other words, imagine that someone gives you an $\varepsilon$ (say, 0.001). You need to find a formula for $\delta$ that depends on this $\varepsilon$ and prove that your $\delta$ works.

Comment: Can you use some of the theorems about continuous functions or do you have to do this from the definition of continuity?

Comment: it should be from the definition sir , @stevengregory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $f(x)=1-\frac{1}{x+1}$ so that
$$
f(x)-f(2)=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{x+1}=\frac{x-2}{3(x+1)}.
$$
Note that for $x$ sufficiently close to $2$, we have $x+1>1$. So for all such $x$, $|f(x)-f(2)|<\frac{|x-2|}{3}$.

The observations above should be enough for you to show $f(x)\to f(2)$ as $x\to 2$. But if you get stuck:

> $$\forall e>0,\exists\delta=\min\{2,3e\}>0:|x-2|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(2)|<e.$$

Comment: Thankyou so much

Comment: but sir while I was working on , I found that from  |x-2| < 1 that |x+1|>2  : by |x+1 -3|<1 , |3 -(x+1)|< 1 then by triangular inequality |x+1|>2  .   is this wrong sir ? I'm getting a totally different answer. @yurnero

Comment: @lasanmanujitha If something is bigger than 2 than it is also bigger than 1.